# Word Problem for Number of Seeds Required with Diminishing Returns

Tags: linear-algebra, word-problem

So I've been trying to wrap my brain around this but it eludes me. The word problem would look something like this:

What is the minimum amount of seeds I need to buy to plant 850 seeds when only 60% of these planted seeds will produce a seed of their own. I can continue planting over and over until I reach my last seed.

I am looking for a formula I can use and plug into Excel - but a mathematical equation would be just great!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are just summing a [geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series).  If you start with $n$ the next generation gives you $0.6n$, the one after that gives $0.6^2n$, then $0.6^3n$ so you want $$850=n(1+0.6+0.6^2+0.6^3+\ldots )=\frac n{1-0.6}\cdot 850\\n=0.4\cdot 850=340 $$

Comment: that's awfully optimistic about the farmer's ability to successfully plant a fraction of a seed.

Comment: @Zackkenyon:  that is true.  I think my approach is in the spirit of the question.  I took the $0.6$ as a probability that each seed produces another.  We could round up a bit to cover.

Comment: @Zackkenyon thanks for not providing any helpful feedback. The question isn't based on a real world scenario.

Comment: @Ross that works! I don't quite see how you got from the first part 850=n(1+0.6+0.62+0.63+…) to this =(n/(1−0.6))*850 could you explain a little more in depth?

Comment: Look up geometric series on Wikipedia.  It is like converting a repeating decimal to a fraction.

Answer (score 0):

1 seed grows 2.5 seeds on average, so divide 850 by 2.5 and you have your answer.
You can use infinite geometric series formula to find expected number of seeds for 1 seed.

Comment: No one seed grows 0.6 seeds.